# YouTube Integration with the app

Tags: search, video, youtube, video-streaming, youtube-data-api

How to make a app which is integrated with youTube and how to enable search functionality in that,which returns the videos I'm searching for.The app must contain a search bar and when queried returns the appropriate videos from youtube

Answer (score 1):

Please clone this repo and see the code. You will defiantly get the solution of your question. https://github.com/orizens/echoes-player

Or Study the Google API for Youtube https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Comment: I'm asking for an Android App